# How to sort JSON array by ID?

Tags: json, postgresql, sql-order-by

I have a problem with data sorting from received JSON array. I need to sort it by ID.

Regular 'ORDER BY' is not working and I can't found something helpful in the Internet.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION test.f_return_test()
   RETURNS json
   LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'

   COST 100
   VOLATILE 
AS $BODY$
DECLARE

BEGIN
    RETURN (SELECT
           json_agg(json_build_object(
              'id_ref_directory', id_ref_catalog,
              'name_directory', rus_name_catalog
              )
           )
        FROM fregat.t_ref_catalog
        WHERE id_parent = 1 
           AND dttmcl IS NULL);
END;
$BODY$;
```

Now all records are displayed in a heap (what should be the last is first and so on). I need to make sorting by ID (i.e., the first key-value pair). Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `ORDER BY <your order column>` into your aggregate function:

[demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=28048e0b9c679a829c55d14022b839df)

```
SELECT
    json_agg(json_build_object('A', col_a, 'B', col_b) ORDER BY id)
FROM 
    ...
```